# What's the encoding of the content of an HTTP request?

Tags: http, encoding, httprequest

Is this defined? Or is it set with a header, similar to the HTTP-response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, HTTP requests can have Content-Type and Content-Encoding headers in exactly the same way as HTTP responses

Comment: so for example POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n<xml .... </xml> . am i right? is this what you are mentioning as sending content type in requests ???

Comment: or it can be even this application/x-www-form-urlencoded ... isn't it?